# Nginx with PHP-FPM reached max_childrent too fastly

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I'm not sure why server reached max_children very fast. About 2-5 mins after restart php-fmp
My server: 4 vCPU, 8GB Ram

FPM log

```
[19-Mar-2020 11:01:11] WARNING: [pool www] child 6984, script '/home/forge/example.com/public/index.php' (request: "GET /index.php") execution timed out (72.300251 sec), terminating
[19-Mar-2020 11:01:11] WARNING: [pool www] child 6847, script '/home/forge/example.com/public/index.php' (request: "GET /index.php") execution timed out (60.922255 sec), terminating
[19-Mar-2020 11:01:11] WARNING: [pool www] child 6841, script '/home/forge/example.com/public/index.php' (request: "GET /index.php") execution timed out (78.432021 sec), terminating
[19-Mar-2020 11:01:11] WARNING: [pool www] child 6828, script '/home/forge/example.com/public/index.php' (request: "POST /index.php") execution timed out (71.056632 sec), terminating
```

FPM conf

```
pm = dynamic
pm.max_childrent = 120
pm.max_requests = 500
pm.max_spare_servers = 72
pm.min_spare_servers = 24
```

Nginx conf

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 4k;
        fastcgi_buffers 32 4k;
    }
```

Comment: Do you run your server with opcache? do you make use of redis? how long does your laravel app need to reach death(eg, execution time until it's done spewing output and destroying everything)?

Comment: @Tschallacka I run server without opacache. i were used redis. i think 1-2 seconds

Comment: a webserver should ideally respond under 50ms. Enable opcache, set up redis and enable it in laravel. Research how to enable static caching so you don't need to re-render dynamic content every view, do dynamic data updates rendering via ajax calls. Keep your requests under 50ms. I have a similar setup and my requests are < 50ms